# How can i print (on new window) two specific panel ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I Want open a new window and it contain both Panel print as...

Hi, How are u?
I am fine..!!

**I use this script for print in Head part**

```
<head> 
<scripttype="text/javascript">
functionPrintPanel() {
var panel = document.getElementById("<%=Pa1.ClientID%>");

varprintWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
printWindow.document.close();
setTimeout(function () {
printWindow.print();
         }, 500);
returnfalse;
     }
</script>
</head>
```

**In Body part I have**

```
<body>
<asp:ImageButtonID="print_btn"runat="server"
ImageUrl="~/images/awards2.jpg"OnClientClick="return 
PrintPanel();"Height="50"Width="50"/>

<asp:Panel ID="Pa1" runat="server">Hi, How are u?</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="Pa2" runat="server">I am fine..!!</asp:Panel>
</body>
```

Through this i will get only "Hi, How are u?" for print, but i want "Hi, How are u? I am fine..!!".....

Comment: Do u want to show whatever is there in panels on a new window?

Comment: I think you will need to make your question question clearer.

Comment: @MicrosoftPS : Yes. But also have to make a paper print of it....

Comment: @Mitesh, as far as the printing to paper is concerned, let the browser handle that.

Comment: @MicrosoftPS : I want browser to make paper print of both panel in one page.

Answer (score 2):

Because those are rendered as a DIV you'll need to put a break in between them. So it would look like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Pa1" runat="server">Hi, How are u?</asp:Panel>
<br />
<asp:Panel ID="Pa2" runat="server">I am fine..!!</asp:Panel>
```

to print the page when it loads do this:

```
<body onload="javascript:windows.print();">
```

Comment: Actually i have many things in my body but I dont want to print all of my body content, just have to print 2 panels. what shall i do??????